# Loading webpage incompletely Phantomjs

Tags: authentication, resources, phantomjs, loading, html

I have problems capturing and loading the webpage: 
https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login

The username and password fields as well as the submit button are missing. What could be the reason? Thanks

As you can see the code listed below waits for each and all the resources to be loaded, one by one.

I did not write the code, however it is excellent and tested by many. The original can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/cjoudrey/1341747
(ALL the credits to the guy who wrote it.)

```
    var resourceWait  = 3000,
    maxRenderWait = 30000,
   url = 'https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login'; //'https://twitter.com/#!/nodejs';

   var page          = require('webpage').create(),
   count         = 0,
   forcedRenderTimeout,
   renderTimeout;

   page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height : 1024 };

   function doRender() {
      page.render('twitter.png');
      phantom.exit();
   }

   page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
      count += 1;
      console.log('> ' + req.id + ' - ' + req.url);
      clearTimeout(renderTimeout);
   };

   page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
     if (!res.stage || res.stage === 'end') {
        count -= 1;
        console.log(res.id + ' ' + res.status + ' - ' + res.url);
        if (count === 0) {
           renderTimeout = setTimeout(doRender, resourceWait);
        }
     }
   };

  page.open(url, function (status) {
     if (status !== "success") {
        console.log('Unable to load url');
        phantom.exit();
     } else {
        forcedRenderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
           console.log(count);
           doRender();
        }, maxRenderWait);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Lazy loading is good, but what about errors, are there any? use `page.onError` callback to receive them. What version is your PhantomJS?

Comment: I am using PhantomJS 2.1.1 and the errors are: EERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set
TRACE:
 -> https://myaccount.nytimes.com/lire_ui/js/dest/auth.bundle.js: 19
 -> https://myaccount.nytimes.com/lire_ui/js/dest/auth.bundle.js: 1 (in function "t")
 -> https://myaccount.nytimes.com/lire_ui/js/dest/auth.bundle.js: 6
 -> https://myaccount.nytimes.com/lire_ui/js/dest/auth.bundle.js: 1 (in function "t")
 -> .../js/dest/auth.bundle.js: 27
 -> https://myaccount.nytimes.com/lire_ui/js/dest/auth.bundle.js: 1 (in function "t")
 ->.../js/dest/auth.bundle.js: 1

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set       is the error related to auth.bundle.js that seems to handle the authentication. Thanks.

Comment: More info on the error related to SET: https://github.com/wallabyjs/wallaby-polymer-sample/issues/5  It seems that phantomjs may not support  ES6 Set.